# Can multiple google tangos operate in the same area?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm currently looking into using the tango for an AR application that requires multiple devices in the same area, learning the same space. It seems like this might not work well as each device projects its own pattern which would create interference?

Comment: In short, yes, you can use two Tango together. But you will see the IR pattern flashes in the other devices.

Answer (score 1):

As you state yourself it will most definitely cause problems if you use several devices in the same space (given that they are "looking" at the same part of the scene), since they are unable to distinguish which reflections comes from which device.

I have not tried using several tangos myself, but I have tried using the tango in a room with a Kinect2 device which caused all the readings to go bananas.

However, there shouldn't be any problem using several tangos in the same area - as long as they are directed in different directions so that they don't pick up each others patterns.

If you want to be able to use multiple depth sensing devices without any concern of each other, you could go for stereo cameras instead (unfortunately there are no tango devices with stereo cameras jet).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is "avoid doing this."

The more complex answer is that yes you can but it's going to be problematic. You'll get more phantom artifacts from stray data, and the visible light camera on the Tango doesn't filter out IR, so you see flashes or the action grid being projected. You don't see this grid ordinarily because the shutter on a single device is synchronized with itself. With multiple devices, it's obnoxious - even when it's not failing (and for the most part, it'll "work") it's not a good experience.

Where you're pointing the devices doesn't "fix" the flicker in the visible camera, by the way. If anything, it's more obnoxious when you're catching bounce light or the camera itself is being hit by another beam.